# How to use use pivot table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I am trying to display the results from my database table using the pivot function but it's not displaying them as I need them. The columns in my database are below:

```
ScoreID, PupilID, Subject, Year, Score
```

I would like to display a pivot table like this:

```
ScoreID, PupilID, Subject, Year1, Year2, Year3, Year4
```

The SQL statement I am using is below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Scores
PIVOT(SUM(Score) 
  FOR Year IN (
  [Year1],[Year2], [Year3], [Year4]
  )) AS PVTTable
  Where (PupilID = 10016)
```

However, this is producing a separate row for every years score. So I end up with one row for English Year 1 score, another row for English Year 2 score, etc. I only want to display one row for each subject with the scores in the columns on that row.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: forgot to mention, Year1, Year2, Year3 and Year4 should contain the scores for that year

Comment: Replace Year1, Year2, etc. with its original values: [2012], [2013], [2014] and let me know what happened.

Comment: But I am using Year1, Year2 etc in the Year column. I dont use 2012, 2013 etc. The scores do appear under the right column header, but they just appear on a new row instead of alongside the other year scores on the same row

Comment: Can you add sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT PupilID, Subject, [Year1], [Year2], [Year3], [Year4]
FROM (
    SELECT PupilID, Subject, Year, Score
    FROM Scores
    --Where (PupilID = 10016) 
    ) AS DT
PIVOT(SUM(Score) FOR Year IN ([Year1],[Year2], [Year3], [Year4])) AS PVT
```

For further information, please see: 
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/2007/09/14/pivots-with-dynamic-columns-in-sql-server-2005/
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/500811/Simple-Way-To-Use-Pivot-In-SQL-Query

Comment: That worked! Thanks for your help Maciej.  I see the problem was that I was including the ScoreID which is unique to each row, once I removed that like your example does it worked